# javascript - http head call - catch 302 redirect and retrieve response headers

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I need to do a http HEAD call and follow a 302 redirect, then grab the response headers.

Basically I need to replicate what I'm able to do with cURL:

```
curl --head 'https://myportal.com/route/thatWillRedirect?x_id=2' -H $'cookie: cookie_1==null; cookie_2=%22c4c8321b-0e....; // all cookies (including session cookies)
```

response:

```
HTTP/2 302 
content-length: 372
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
location: https://redirect_url
server: 
x-robots-tag: noindex
true_route: /true/route
true_status: Ok
correlation_id: 0001-1111
s-n: vdrGt
pics-label: (pics-1.1 "http://www.icra.org/ratingsv02.html" comment "ICRAonline EN v2.0" l r (nz 1 vz 1 lz 1 oz 1 cz 1) "http://www.rsac.org/ratingsv01.html" l r (n 0 s 0 v 0 l 0))
date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 13:29:23 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=156768000; includeSubDomains
cache-control: private
```

That http call will be performed within the javascript scope of a browser page of a logged in user (se there's no need to pass the session cookies).

So far I tried with `XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch` and `JQuery.ajax()` but none of them seems to be able to handle the 302 redirect in the way I want.

XMLHttpRequest:

```
function handleRedirectWithXHR(){
    var xhr0 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr0.loadend = function (data) {
        console.log(xhr0.responseURL);
    }
    xhr0.onload = function() {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
            console.log(this.responseURL);
        }
    };
    var url = 'https://myportal.com/route/thatWillRedirect?x_id=2';
    xhr0.open('HEAD', url, true);
    xhr0.send(null);
}
```

fetch:

```
function handleRedirectWithFetch(){
    let url = 'https://myportal.com/route/thatWillRedirect?x_id=2';
    fetch(url,{
        method: "HEAD", 
        redirect: "manual",
    
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.debug(error);
    });
}
```

jQuery ajax:

```
function handleRedirectWithJQueryAjax(XMLHttpRequest) {
    let url = 'https://myportal.com/route/thatWillRedirect?x_id=2';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'HEAD',
        statusCode: {     
            302: function (data) {
                console.log('302: Occurred');
                console.log(data);
                // Handle 302 here.
            }
        },
        success:
            function (result, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(result);
            
            },
        error:  function (jqXHR, timeout, message) {
                        var contentType = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                        if (jqXHR.status === 302) {
                            console.log("redirect catched in error");
                        }
                }

        });
}
```

only with `fetch` I'm able to not follow the redirect, however I'm not able to retrieve the response headers (empty object).

For all af these implementations, from the console network browser, I can see the 302 request made correctly and the response headers retrieved.

Any help on this?
Thanks

Comment: The browser handles the 302 before the call gets into javascript space.  Are you able to send a different status code from the server?

Comment: @DavinTryon unfortunately I have no control on the server response

Comment: Not is possible from AJAX client side. But some idea is that you create a server page that can request the page. Client > Your server Page > target url.

Comment: @toto not feasible that way either, otherwise I'd already been down that road: to perform that call I need session cookies to be sent to the backend server, and it's not possible to retrieve them via javascript. So it's something that has to be done client side :(

Comment: The cookie session is saved in the header request of the ajax.

Comment: @toto not following, please provide a working example of what you're saying. the cookies eventually needed have the 'HttpOnly' attribute set, which makes them nt accessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API (see inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie)

Comment: from server side language: java or php ?

Comment: @toto again, I have no control over the server response here.